# Something wrong with the code?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a function that fetches the id for a song. The id is a primary field and autoincrement. But somehow whenever I call this function it returns me -1 that is result not found. Is there something wrong with how I am approaching the problem?

```
int getIdForSong(Song song){

        String selectQuery = "SELECT id FROM " + TABLE_SONG + " WHERE " + SONG_TITLE + "= ' " + song.getSongTitle() + "' AND " + ARTIST_NAME + "= ' " + song.getArtistName()+" ' ";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.moveToNext() && cursor != null){
            int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
            return id;
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Your select query needs spaces before `=` parts, and no spaces after and before `'`. Better use the easier and less error prone `query()` method, it will add `'` for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see extra spaces:

```
' " + song.getArtistName()+" '
```

So if your Artist name is "Green Day" it becomes " Green Day "

Similarly:

```
"= ' " + song.getSongTitle() + "'
```

So "Boulevard Of Broken Dreams" becomes " Boulevard Of Broken Dreams"

Answer (score 0):

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT id FROM " + TABLE_SONG + " WHERE " + SONG_TITLE + "= '" + song.getSongTitle() + "' AND " + ARTIST_NAME + "= '" + song.getArtistName()+"' ";
```